# Vuforia IOS crash. Terminated due to memory issue

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, crash, vuforia

My app works on Android but on IOS it crashes. Is that about vuforia or what? If i delete image targets and background it works. If i delete image targets only, the scene doesn't open but not crash. (sorry for my english) Can you help me? I use vufroia 6.2 and Unity 5.4.2f1 (the project created on unity 5.4.2.f2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the reason. I delete some sprites in animations and it works.